# VST built-in annotation support

Tags: c, coq, verification, formal-verification, verifiable-c

I got a question, about VST support for compcert built-in annotation mechanism.
Suppose we have a **C** function:

```
int f(int *p) {
  // p is not null
  __builtin_annot("_p <> nullval");
  int t = *p;
  return t;
}
```

And specification for it:

```
Definition f_spec : ident * funspec :=
  DECLARE _f
    WITH p_b : block, p_ofs : ptrofs, a : Z
    PRE [(tptr tint)]
      PROP ()
      PARAMS (Vptr p_b p_ofs)
      GLOBALS ()
      SEP (data_at Tsh (tptr tint) (Vint (Int.repr a)) (Vptr p_b p_ofs))
    POST [tint]
      PROP ()
      LOCAL (temp ret_temp (Vint (Int.repr a)))
      SEP (data_at Tsh (tptr tint) (Vint (Int.repr a)) (Vptr p_b p_ofs)).
```

When I'm trying to prove this, I got to the state, where I have this statement `(builtin EF_annot 1 "_p <> nullval" []([]);`

to prove next and I can't move forward from here.

`hint` tactic doesn't help, `forward` and it's variations(if, loop, etc) doesn't work either.

So the question is, how(if i can) I move forward from here?